# Are the "normal" ASCII values guaranteed in Java?

Tags: java, ascii

A program like this:

```
class AsciiTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        assert 'a' == 97;
        assert 'b' == 98;
        // etc
    }
}
```

runs fine on the system I'm using but is it guaranteed to run OK everywhere?  I want to write code that does things like

```
if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') { // c is a lowercase roman letter
```

and I'm not sure if that works everywhere.  Where is this kind of thing specified?

Comment: Yes it will work well because JAVA uses Unicode on all platforms.

Comment: Reference: [JLS 3.10.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.4)

Answer (score 4):

Yes.

Java internally uses [Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode). The Unicode code point for each character is specified by the [Unicode Consortium](http://unicode.org/).

For all characters that have ASCII encodings the [Unicode code point](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0000.pdf) is the same as the ASCII value, it is consistent on all platforms, and it will not change in the future.